# How to add multiple ips to ubuntu 12.04 server?

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, ip, ifconfig

i hope that some can help me here.

I have bought 6 additional IP:S and i need to run two gaming servers at same time for same game.

So i need to add another ip so i can run these two servers at same time.

I tried to add another IP (one of these what i bought from my host) to etc/network/interface and it looks like this[this is what i tryed [my try to add new one eth1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zKV9.jpg)

but i cant see that ip in my when i run : ifconfig [this is ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0ulP.jpg)

Comment: Well, you need a separate interface for each IP, and ifconfig is only showing eth0. Maybe you just need to wait for your service provider to add interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`

Add a second block, for e.g

`auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.0.2
gateway 192.168.0.254
netmask 255.255.255.0`

The key is the :1, you can do this for additional IPs on eth0, eth0:2, eth0:3 etc

`sudo service network-manager restart` should initialise them all, or just reboot for a proper test.

---

Another method can be done by running the `ip` command:

`ip address add 192.168.99.37/24 dev eth0`

That simply adds another IP to that NIC. run `ip addr` to see the additional IPs

Info from [here](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/add-secondary-ip-linux.html)

### EDIT:

I was testing this out, only `ip addr` worked OK.
If you're in Ubuntu 15 you could look at `nmtui` command which does all which the desktop "Edit connections" does.
Set your IP to *static* then add the additional ones.